How can I implement a caching mechanism in Jenkins to reuse fetched and compiled artifacts across multiple runner jobs managed by a master job?
I'm using Jenkins with a master job that runs multiple runner jobs each night. Each runner performs a test that includes fetching from Git and compiling the environment. To save time, I want to ensure that each environment is fetched and compiled only once if it hasn't been done previously. My goal is to cache these environments within the master job, so they can be reused by the runners during the session, and then delete all the data at the end.
How would you implement this mechanism?
I've tried saving data into a directory in Linux, but i preffer all of it under the umbrella of a single job in Jenkins - the master job.


How would you implement this mechanism?

I would set up a dockerfile and just depend on docker layer caching.
For uploading and caching between docker daemons, I would use nexus or gitlab as docker repository.
